# QField Photos and External Storage

Tags: qgis, qfield, photos

I am using QGIS 3.12 and QField 1.5.3 on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 9).

My project allows collection of photos. This works when stored on Internal Storage, but not when stored in 'QField directory on external storage'.  The native camera app is displayed, you can take a picture, but no photo is created.

I am aware that this was a known issue some time ago, but thought it had been resolved.  I thought I had had it working on external storage, but not now.

Is it still the case that photo storage will only work on Internal Storage?

In app manager on the tablet, I have tried having QField set to internal and external storage, but it makes no difference. I have also cleared the cache and rebooted several times, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I am now saving photos in external storage, with photo-naming (available in QGIS3.14). I am not sure what was wrong before, but the external folder must be the Qfield folder on external storage , i.e. sd card/android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files/ or its subfolders.